# ASP.NET Core 2 Console.WriteLine Output Not Appearing in Docker Logs

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core

What I'm trying to achieve is for the output of `ILogger.LogError` (and other `ILogger` methods) to appear in the logs for my Docker container, but to take `ILogger` out of the equation for now, I've just created a vanilla out-of-the-box Web App API project using the standard template in Visual Studio 2019, seleding .NET Core 2.2 and ticking the box to enable Docker support. Then I added `Console.WriteLine("test")` in a couple of places that I know for certain will be hit when the application loads (and when a page is loaded). I'm seeing nothing in the container logs in Kitematic, and nothing when I run `docker logs`.

I'm fairly inexperienced with both Docker and Unix, but as I understood it, `Console.WriteLine` is supposed to send it's output to `stdout` which in turn is supposed to be written directly to Docker's logs automatically. Is there some simple trick to get it to behave that way?

Docker file: (unmodified from template default)

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-stretch-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-stretch AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj", "WebApplication1/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebApplication1"
RUN dotnet build "WebApplication1.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApplication1.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication1.dll"]
```

Comment: Hi .. have you tried to attaching to the docker container with the cmd and see if you can see logs ?

Comment: Yeah. Nothing happens. At least I think I've done that right. I used docker attach container_name and then refreshed a page that would cause a Console.WriteLine and I saw nothing in the command window where I'd run docker attach.